# Excel VBA - Save Userform Changes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Is it possible to save changes to a Label Caption in a userform in Excel VBA, so that they are permanently saved, and only changed when you enter a new change?
I have checked, that the code is changing the caption, but I cannot get it to stick, so that it is still there next time I open the userform.
Thank you in advance

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

'resets participants email and name
    If Me.optProg.Value = True Then
        Me.NameLabelProg.Caption = Me.CB_Part.Value
        Me.MailLabelProg.Caption = Me.TB_Mail.Value
    ElseIf Me.optTester.Value = True Then
        Me.MailLabelTest.Caption = Me.CB_Part.Value
        Me.NameLabelTest.Caption = Me.TB_Mail.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome!  Is this for Excel VBA?  If so, I'll update your question and propose an answer for you as soon as I can.

Comment: @k1dfr0std yes, this is for excel vba

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I know the Question itself lists it, but the Tags did not match - updated the tags and proposed an answer.  Let me know if you have any questions.  If the below works for you or you need more clarification, I'll help you out as much as I can.

Comment: You could have Excel look up a value on a sheet when the form loads and apply that value to the label caption.  Edit: Just noticed that's what @k1dfr0std suggest at the end of his answer - sorry, stopped reading answer as it was playing with changing stuff that was set at design time.

Comment: @Darren, Yeah - the OP's original question was to do it permanently so the changes were done when the user looks at the UserForm (presuming without the Initialize event doing anything), but that's a risk, so I offered both options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this userform example and you'll find answers to many of your questions.

[image]

[Source of userform](https://eksi30.com/the-updated-excel-userform/)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the lengthy answer initially, but there is a bit of a risk involved with making permanent changes to `UserForms` through VBA.

In order to change the caption of a Label (or `UserForm` or any other `Control` permanently, you will have to "*`Trust access to the VBA project object model`*" in order to do it via VBA code.  Now, while this is *possible* it is not usually *recommended* because it can seriously put a user's PC at Risk should they encounter a Macro developed for nefarious purposes.

(To clarify in case the question is raised, your end user(s) will have to make this Trust setting change on *their* PC's as well . . . you cannot make the change on your PC, setup the code to work and then hand the file over to another user and have it work on their PC without them making the same change.)

There are methods to do this programmatically, *but, this falls into the "nefarious Macro" rabbit hole and would need to be disclosed to the end user you are making this change. . .  Research at your own risk.*

If you are OK with putting *yourself* at risk, you can do it using VBA similar to the following snippet I found [here.](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-48994.html)  You will have to substitute your `UserForm` name and `Label` name as appropriate.  I tested it on my own `UserForm` and it works as expected.

```
Sub Change_Userform()
  ThisDocument.VBProject.VBComponents("Userform1").Designer.Controls("Label1").Caption = "Some new caption text"
End Sub
```

You will need to do some research on how to "Trust access to the VBA project object model" yourself and understand the risks to do this in order for the above code to work.

If I understand the *intent* of what you are trying to accomplish correctly though, you could achieve this effect without having to put yourself or your end user(s) at risk.

(Most end user(s) typically would not have direct access to the VBA Designer where they would see the `UserForm's` `un-initialized` environment.)  To do this, you would have to place your code in the `UserForm's` [image: Initialize] event.

The following assumes your `Me.optProg.Value` and `Me.optTester.Value` are `Option Buttons` which a user would change.  If you create a "Settings" sheet in the file, you can place values in the cells of this sheet and then *hide* it so the users do not modify them directly.  Then, reference the values of the cells and change the appearances of the `Option Buttons` at the same time as the `UserForm's` launch.  (Additionally, you can set the `Click` events of the `Option Buttons` to change the values of the same cells and provide that change to affect the `UserForm's` `Initialize` event when called, but this should get you going in the right direction.)

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  'The Range below is completely up to you.  
'Since you are using Boolean True/False, a simple "1" or "0" _
   is easy to use to make the changes.

  If Thisworkbook.Sheets("Some_Settings").Range("A1").Value = "1" Then
    Me.optProg.Value = True
  Else
    Me.optTester.Value = True
  End If

'do some other code here as needed to finish initializing the UserForm

  If Me.optProg.Value = True Then
      Me.NameLabelProg.Caption = Me.CB_Part.Value
      Me.MailLabelProg.Caption = Me.TB_Mail.Value
  ElseIf Me.optTester.Value = True Then
      Me.MailLabelTest.Caption = Me.CB_Part.Value
      Me.NameLabelTest.Caption = Me.TB_Mail.Value
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found a different solution, where I am using a hidden label on the sheet as an intermediary, and then use ´´´thisworkbook.save´´´ to save it. Afterwards, it's simply userfrom initialize()

Comment: Awesome!  That works too - glad you found a solution!